# ASP.NET code source updating

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I built a website and I want to redirect a site built in asp.net 
( similar example `www.mysite.net/Front/ContactUs.aspx?Page=ContactUs&mn=ContactUs`) to my new site.

the problem is that I have not found where I can make changes in aspx code, I looked into the source code but in vain. 
The project contains a lot of files of code, I do not really know what part of the code I have to show you.

Is ASP's projects have a syntax to define the site URLs? 
Please I need help, how to make this redirection , and where I can make changes.

Thanks.

Comment: youre going to need to be more specific and show us some code

Comment: The project contains a lot of files of code, I do not really know what part of the code I have to show you. 
I asked whether the asp projects have a different syntax for defining URL,  because I do not even have an idea what file I need to change!

Comment: start with the part where youre trying to do the redirect

Comment: Is there a `private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` function in your `ContactUs.aspx` code file (c# or vb)? ... and should the whole `ContactUs` page be loaded from your new site?

Comment: ... Or should all site be redirected ?

Comment: LGSon, no i want just redirect one page like this 'www.mysite.net/Front/ContactUs.aspx?Page=ContactUs&mn=ContactUs' to new page built in Django. I found a file that all pages inherits from, it's front.master, it contains all web site URLs. It's Ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you want to redirect all requests or just select individual files, partially or fully, they all normally have a function called `Page_Load`.

For every file you want to be redirected, you can use this code piece.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check whether the browser remains
    // connected to the server.
    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        // Redirect
        Response.Redirect("http://new.website.com/", false);
    }
    else
    {
        // Browser is not connected, stop all response processing
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

---

If you want the full site to be redirected, you can use the this function, in `global.asax` file

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

  <script runat="server">

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://new.website.com/", false);
        Response.End();
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very useful.